# Postgres create/restore taking lot of time on amazon ec2

Tags: postgresql, optimization, amazon-ec2, disk-io, iostat

I have a amazon ec2 instance(SAY S1)(4core-7GB memory) using Ubuntu 12.04, which is running my web app with `postgresql 9.1`. All the postgres data is stored on to a different ssd volume(not root) of 100 GB. (Write now its currently 26% full only ) .

Suddenly from a day or two few postgres actions started taking lot of time. Create command (52 seconds) and restore a db (9 mins now, previously 50 seconds max ) .

By running iostat while running postgres commands I can confirm that its IOPS of ec2 volume which has reached to its limit (3 IOPS/GB equals 300 IOPS for 100GB volume ) . Can see it in below after running this command `iostat -d 5 -x -p xvdf` .

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvdf              0.35     2.28    1.20  298.99    19.65 13082.19    87.29    23.42   78.03   64.19   78.09   3.29  98.75

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvdf              0.00     1.80    0.00  297.40     0.00 13067.20    87.88   126.47  420.75    0.00  420.75   3.35  99.76

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvdf              0.00     1.80    0.00  297.40     0.00 13067.20    87.88   126.32  417.95    0.00  417.95   3.35  99.76

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvdf              0.00     1.80    0.00  297.80     0.00 13093.60    87.94   131.70  440.82    0.00  440.82   3.36 100.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvdf              0.00     0.00    0.00  301.00     0.00 13225.60    87.88   129.36  422.97    0.00  422.97   3.32  99.84
```

[IO characteristics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-io-characteristics.html) on aws says that each IOPS takes a request of 256KiB or less so is the postgres using smaller blocks of data to write back resulting more number of IOPS request ?

While I have another ec2 instance(Say S2) with 100GB volume(95% full right now ) with postgres data being on root volume and its performing great. So size of volume is something I am sure doesn't matter here .

The affected volume of S1 only store postgres data still I can see the below stats by iostat. Not sure why the stats are like that and how could I reduce the postgres commands time without increasing the size of the volume . (While all operations 3GB memory is always free )

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvdf              0.34     2.29    1.23  298.93    20.10 13079.03    87.28    26.19   87.26   66.96   87.34   3.29  98.78

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvdf              0.00     2.40    0.60  299.00     4.80 13020.80    86.95   132.22  434.48  108.00  435.14   3.34 100.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvdf              0.00     3.20    4.40  295.20    43.20 12866.40    86.18   122.18  417.09  142.00  421.20   3.34 100.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvdf              0.00     2.80    2.40  297.20    23.20 12940.00    86.54   122.70  401.11  124.00  403.34   3.34  99.92

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvdf              0.00     3.40    4.80  294.80    46.40 12840.00    86.02   127.43  433.15  161.67  437.57   3.34  99.92
```

Note : The affected volume of postgres contains 100 different postgres db with average size of 110 MB/db (but honestly I don't think this is in any case a problem )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally this issue got resolved. And found that it was [postgres statistics collector](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/monitoring-stats.html) which was running in the background and was issuing lots of small  (less then 256 KB) io requests(as we have 100+ dbs)  eating out all the 300 IOPS for 100GB disk . Resulting all postgres actions were scheduled in queue and were taking lot of time to process.

Postgres document says

> The statistics collector transmits the collected information to
>   backends (including autovacuum) through temporary files. These files
>   are stored in the [`pg_stat_tmp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-statistics.html#GUC-STATS-TEMP-DIRECTORY) subdirectory. When the postmaster shuts
>   down, a permanent copy of the statistics data is stored in the global
>   subdirectory. For increased performance, the parameter
>   stats_temp_directory can be pointed at a RAM-based file system,
>   decreasing physical I/O requirements.

I pointed the `pg_stats_tmp` file to ram instead disk by mounting pg_stats_tmp in tmpfs filesystem . This [blog](http://hacksoclock.blogspot.in/2014/04/putting-statstempdirectory-on-ramdisk.html) explains how to do it step by step .